# How to receive data from client using socket.io events inside express controller?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io, angular6

I am using Express framework with TypeScript:

I want to get client location at login using Socket IO, so on the client side, i made an emit event on login page. On the server side i tried to integrate a socket event into the login controller, which is placed before the response is sent back to the client, but the event from the server fires up just after i'm already signed in and clicked on sign out button which leads me to login page again (this is the moment when i receive the location message on server side from console.log(data)).

This is how the authentication controller file (auth.controller.ts) looks like:

```
 import { io } from '../server/https';
 ....
 ..

 public authenticate(req: Request, res: Response) {
   if(req.body.email && req.body.password) {
     ....
     ..

     io.on('connection', (socket: SocketIO.Socket) => {
       console.log('New Socket Connected!');
       socket.on('client-location', (data) => {
         console.log(data);
       });
       socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
         console.log(reason);
       });
     });
     res.status(200).json({
       resType: 'success',
       token: 'Bearer ' + token,
       userId: user.id,
       message: 'Authenticated.',
       loginNumber: result.session.length
     });

   };
    ....
    ..

}
```

The { io } import in the auth.controller.ts is the exported io constant from https.ts file.
Below is the https.ts file:

```
 import socketIO from 'socket.io';
 import HTTPS from 'https';

 import app from '../app/index';
 ....
 ..

 const options = {
     cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('../../../certificates/ca.crt')),
     key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('../../../certificates/ca.key'))
 }

 export const server = HTTPS.createServer(options, app)
 .listen(process.env.HTTP_SERVER_PORT, () => {
     console.log(`Platform Server is running from 
  ${process.env.HTTP_SERVER_HOST}, port: ${process.env.HTTP_SERVER_PORT}`);
 });

 export const io = socketIO.listen(server);
```

Something is not synchronized and i don't get it.

The client side is wrote in Angular 6 and the component from where the event is emited is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

import { env } from '../../../../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'login-form',
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-form.component.css']
})

export class LoginFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public positionOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      maximumAge: 0
  };
  public LoginFormModel: any = {};
  private URL = `${env.WS_SERVER_URL}:${env.HTTP_SERVER_PORT}`;
  private socket;

  constructor(private loginController: LoginService,
   private router: Router) { 
    this.socket = io(this.URL);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  public emitLocation() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        const { latitude: lat, longitude: lng } = position.coords;
        console.log({ lat, lng });
        this.socket.emit('client-location', { lat, lng });
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }, this.positionOptions);
  }

  loginEvent() {
      this.loginController.login(this.LoginFormModel.email.value, 
      this.LoginFormModel.password.value)
      .subscribe(
         result => {
           this.loginController.createSession('token', result.token);
           this.emitLocation();
           this.router.navigate(['user/profile']);
         },
         err => {
         console.log(err);
         });
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Would you mind sharing your client-side code?
At which moment exactly is the location data supposed to be sent to the server?

Comment: For sure, the client side is wrote in Angular 6

Comment: the location data is sent to server right after the token is sent to sent to the session storage

Comment: The socket is not associated with the client executing the request to http-endpoint. You have different connections for ws and http. In any case, you need to identify and match the connected clients and clients executing the HTTPS request. You will have confusion.

Comment: When authenticate the first person, you can get the coordinates of the other person.

Comment: i receive the location data, but after i sign in, sign out and get back on the login page.

Comment: You should move `io.on('connect',...)` outside of the authenticate function, the current implementation will register another callback for every invocation of authenticate.

Comment: Or is it better to keep it simple and send the location to server in req.body? The idea is to save those location coordinates to database in a session field and i need to make it work for every person at every login, that's why i placed the `io.on('connect',...)` inside authenticate function.